# Javascript issue, my radio button & function works in Google Chrome but not in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When the page load, function will be run based on radio button selected.

It will add or delete html element.

This function works in Google Chrome but not in IE 11. Appreciate your help on this issue.

**Error in IE as below:**
[screenshot of error shown in IE 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOC1f.png)

**My radio button html:**

```
<div style="width: 600px; float:left; height:auto; margin:10px">  


                            <p id="purposerequesttitletext">
                                The request of this security paper is for:
                            </p><br>
                            <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose1" value="New" checked onclick="purposeAlert()"> New Project, Service or System<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose2" value="Upgrade" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Upgrade, Enhancement or Amendment of current productiion servers<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose3" value="POC" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Proof of Concept System/Service or Temporary use<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose4" value="Operational_Use" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Operational Use<br>
                            <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose5" class="purpose5" value="Port" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Port Amendment/Open Port for Testing of Firewall Lockdown Activity<br><br><br>

                            <div style="width: auto; height:auto;float:left;" class="myGenie">          

                            </div>
                            <div style="width: auto; height:auto; float:left;"  class="prevRFC">

                            </div>
                            <div style="width: auto; height:auto; float:left; margin-left:10px" class="currentRFC">

        </div>
</div>
```

**My js/jquery code:**

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                purposeAlert();
            });

            function purposeAlert() {

                selectRFC = $('input:radio[name=purpose]:checked').val();
                console.log(selectRFC);          
                if (selectRFC != "Port") {


                    if ($(".prevRFC").children().length > 1) {
                        $("#prevRFCnum").remove();
                        $("#prevRFCnumipt").remove();
                        $("#myprevbr").remove();
                        $("#currentRFCnum").remove();
                        $("#currentRFCnumipt").remove();
                        $("#mycurrbr").remove();
                    }

                    if ($(".myGenie").children().length < 1) {
                        $(".myGenie").append("<label id='ticketnum'>Mygenie+ Ticket Number:</label>");
                        $(".myGenie").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='ticketnumipt'>");
                        $(".myGenie").append("<br id='ticketbr'>");
                        $("#ticketnumipt").val(mygenie);

                    }
                }
                else {
                    if ($(".prevRFC").children().length < 1) { 
                        $("#ticketnum").remove();
                        $("#ticketnumipt").remove();
                        $("#ticketbr").remove();

                        $(".prevRFC").append("<label id='prevRFCnum'>Previous RFC Number:</label>");
                        $(".prevRFC").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='prevRFCnumipt'>");
                        $(".prevRFC").append("<br id='myprevbr'>");
                        $(".currentRFC").append("<label id='currentRFCnum'>Current RFC Number:</label>");
                        $(".currentRFC").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='currentRFCnumipt'>");
                        $(".currentRFC").append("<br id='mycurrbr'>");
                        $("#prevRFCnumipt").val(prevRFC);
                        $("#currentRFCnumipt").val(currentRFC);
                    }


                }
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Your actual code is missing. Your HTML has multiple inputs with the same `id` which is wrong

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I fix the id but still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

It seems that you are using JQuery validate plugin, please check the JQuery validate version, perhaps the issue is related to the JQuery validate version, please try to use [the latest version](https://jqueryvalidation.org/).

> purposeAlert is undefined

Can't reproduce this error on my side. it seems that everything works well, I have create a sample using your code, it just show me the Error: 'mygenie' is undefined, after change your code as below, everything works well:

```
<div style="width: 600px; float:left; height:auto; margin:10px">


    <p id="purposerequesttitletext">
        The request of this security paper is for:
    </p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose1" value="New" checked onclick="purposeAlert()"> New Project, Service or System<br>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose2" value="Upgrade" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Upgrade, Enhancement or Amendment of current productiion servers<br>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose3" value="POC" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Proof of Concept System/Service or Temporary use<br>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose4" value="Operational_Use" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Operational Use<br>
    <input type="radio" name="purpose" id="purpose5" class="purpose5" value="Port" onclick="purposeAlert()"> Port Amendment/Open Port for Testing of Firewall Lockdown Activity<br><br><br>

    <div style="width: auto; height:auto;float:left;" class="myGenie">

    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; height:auto; float:left;" class="prevRFC">

    </div>
    <div style="width: auto; height:auto; float:left; margin-left:10px" class="currentRFC">

    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        purposeAlert();
    });

    function purposeAlert() {

        selectRFC = $('input:radio[name=purpose]:checked').val();
        console.log(selectRFC);
        if (selectRFC != "Port") {


            if ($(".prevRFC").children().length > 1) {
                $("#prevRFCnum").remove();
                $("#prevRFCnumipt").remove();
                $("#myprevbr").remove();
                $("#currentRFCnum").remove();
                $("#currentRFCnumipt").remove();
                $("#mycurrbr").remove();
            }

            if ($(".myGenie").children().length < 1) {
                $(".myGenie").append("<label id='ticketnum'>Mygenie+ Ticket Number:</label>");
                $(".myGenie").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='ticketnumipt'>");
                $(".myGenie").append("<br id='ticketbr'>");
                $("#ticketnumipt").val("mygenie");

            }
        }
        else {
            if ($(".prevRFC").children().length < 1) {
                $("#ticketnum").remove();
                $("#ticketnumipt").remove();
                $("#ticketbr").remove();

                $(".prevRFC").append("<label id='prevRFCnum'>Previous RFC Number:</label>");
                $(".prevRFC").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='prevRFCnumipt'>");
                $(".prevRFC").append("<br id='myprevbr'>");
                $(".currentRFC").append("<label id='currentRFCnum'>Current RFC Number:</label>");
                $(".currentRFC").append("<input type='text' class='form-control' id='currentRFCnumipt'>");
                $(".currentRFC").append("<br id='mycurrbr'>");
                $("#prevRFCnumipt").val("prevRFC");
                $("#currentRFCnumipt").val("currentRFC");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The result like this:

[image]

In the F12 developer Console tools, try to click the link under the error message, then, redirect to the location of the issue code. Make sure they are on the same page and before calling the purposeAlert() method, ensure you have defined it.